# How to give full read and write permission in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "true"
    }
}
```

Please mention complete code that I have to put in the Rules section of Firebase since I am facing error while entering the above code.

Comment: The rules you refer to in your question ARE correct to "give anyone, even people who are not users of your app, read and write access to your database", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart. If you need something different, tell us what is your exact goal in terms of access rights? Please share your database structure and the desired access rights (who can read what,etc..).

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: Actually my target is to verify a user using mobile number and active that user manually. Means the user should only be allowed to signin after manual activation. As we know, by default, in firebase after successful verification of mobile number user can signin but I want manual activation of user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the Real Time Database and not Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

But this is not secure.
Firebase say that **"Your security rules are not secure. Any authenticated user can steal, modify, or delete data in your database."**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using firebase then the rules below apply as an example, for firestore the rule structure is a little different.

To change the rulles you can go to the firebase project area Database on the left menu and then rules on the blue menu.

However I need to mention that if you are doing a `firebase deploy` you WILL OVERWRITE these rulles with the contents of `database.rules.json` that is in your top level for firebase project structure and `firestore.rules` for firestore.

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "FirstlevelNode_1": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid == 'NyEFUW2fdsbgv3WRQRHl4K4YWTxf17Dgc2' || auth.uid == '34x5KfLnk4fgyrjMtvvanb4VSypenBC83'"
    },
    "FirstlevelNode_2_with_children": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid == 'NyEFUWv3WRQRHl4K4YWTdsfdxf17Dgc2' || auth.uid == '34x5KfLnk4Mtvvanb4VSypfdsahenBC83'",

        "SecondLevelNode_1": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": true,
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || auth.uid == 'NyEFUWv3WRQRHlddsfsadsa4K4YWTxf17Dgc2' '"
            }
        },
        "SecondLevelNode_2": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid "
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}